# Alerts show hide based on user response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the plunker link for the below-mentioned requirements:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Ae8Pit3sFqvnM9gat0za?p=preview

```js
// Code goes here
$(document).ready(function() {
  showAlerts();
});

function showAlerts() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#alerts').show("fast", function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#alerts").hide();
        $(".alertsBadge").attr("data-badge", "2");
      }, 10000);
    });
  }, 10000);
  $(".alertsBadge").click(function() {
    $("#alerts").toggle();
  });
}

function saveAlertResponse() {
  $("#alerts input[type='radio']:checked").closest('.alertHolder').hide();
  $("#successBanner").show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="alertsBadge" id="alertsBadge" data-badge=""><span class="fa fa-bell">Alerts</span></a>
<div id="alerts" style="display:none;">
  <div id="successBanner" style="display:none;">Your response has been saved</div><br/>
  <form>
    <div id="shouldRead">You should answer the following:</div><br/>
    <div class="alertHolder">
      <div>Your gender?</div>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
    </div><br/>
    <div class="alertHolder">
      <div>You smoke??</div>
      <input type="radio" name="smoke" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
      <input type="radio" name="smoke" value="No"> No<br>
    </div><br/>
    <div class="alertHolder">
      <div>You drink??</div>
      <input type="radio" name="drink" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
      <input type="radio" name="drink" value="No"> No<br>
    </div><br/>
    <input type="submit" onclick="saveAlertResponse(); return false;" />
```

Requirements are as follows:

1. On the first page load, the alerts div should open/show after 2 minutes.
   A) Scenario 1: If the user doesn't respond to any of the questions
   i. It should hide after 2 minutes and reappear again in 2 minutes and continue to do so if he doesn't answer
   ii. When it hides, the badge on top of alert should show the number of questions that are unanswered.
   B) Scenario 2: If the user responds to any of the questions
   i. The question that has been responded to-should hide on click of saving and a banner should appear on top saying "response saved". After this, in ten seconds the whole alerts div should hide and the badge on top of alert should show the number of questions that are unanswered.
   ii. Again the alert should show after 2 minutes if any of the questions are unanswered
   iii.  Div with id should read should also disappear. If he answers all the questions, banner should appear on top saying "response saved". After this, in ten seconds the whole alerts div should hide and the badge on top of alert should disappear.
2. Whenever the alert opens "response saved"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var interval = 0;
    var form_submitted = false;
    var periodic_interval_check;


$(".alertsBadge").click(function(){
    $("#alerts form").show();
    $("#alerts").toggle();

    if($("#alerts:visible").length==1){
      periodic_interval_check = setInterval(updateDiv,1000);
    }else{
     clearInterval(periodic_interval_check)
    }

});

function updateDiv(){
  var answered   =  check_answered_count()
  var unanswered =  3 - check_answered_count()


  if(interval == 120 && form_submitted){
       /* if intervall reaches 2 the user is inactive hide element/s */

       alert('Form Submitted::    Answered:'+ answered +' unanswered:' + unanswered)
       $("#successBanner").show();
       $("#alerts form").hide();

       clearInterval(periodic_interval_check)
   }
   else if(interval == 120 && !form_submitted){
      alert('Form Not Submitted::    Answered:'+ answered +' unanswered:' + unanswered)
      interval = 0;
      /* restart once again */
      $("#alerts").hide();
      if($("#alerts:hidden").length==1){
        clearInterval(periodic_interval_check)
      }


   }
   interval = interval+1;
   console.log(interval);
}

function saveAlertResponse(){
  form_submitted = true
  var answered   =  check_answered_count()
  var unanswered =  3 - check_answered_count()
  if(check_answered_count()==3){
    clearInterval(periodic_interval_check)
    $("#successBanner").show();
    $("#alerts form").hide();
  }else{
    $("#alerts form").hide();
  }
  interval = 0;
  alert('Form Submitted::    Answered:'+ answered +' unanswered:' + unanswered)
}


function check_answered_count(){
  return $("#alerts input[type='radio']:checked").length
}

$("form").on("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  saveAlertResponse()
})

});
```